# SQL error converting varchar to int on string when selecting count as well

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, int, varchar

I have a SQL query that is used to create a text file with a header row, detail rows, and finally a row with a 'X rows selected' message. Because it's for a report that uses a capital cedilla for the delimiter, I select the entire header row as a single string (truncated with an ellipsis to save space):

```
SELECT 
       'REC_TYPE'+CHAR(199)+'PLAN_ID'+CHAR(199)+...+'DATE_ANSWERED'
UNION ALL

SELECT  REC_TYPE+CHAR(199)+
        PLAN_ID+CHAR(199)+
        ...+
        Convert(char(10),DATE_ANSWERED,101)

FROM
       #My_Temp_Table  

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*) + 'rows selected'

FROM
       #My_Temp_Table
```

If I'm not including the row count via SQL code, the whole thing works fine. For some reason, though, adding the row count line via union causes the query to throw a conversion error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'REC_TYPEÇPLAN_IDÇ...DATE_ANSWERED' to data type int.
```

What can I do to the row count part to prevent that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because COUNT returns an int and then you are trying to add that to a string. Everything will attempt to be converted to an int because of datatype precendence.

Simply change your last query to something like this.

```
SELECT convert(varchar(10), COUNT(*)) + 'rows selected'
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!